# Razor Pages: Set cookie from _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, culture, razor-pages

In _Layout.cshtml I have menu to change language of the application, like:

```html
<nav id="nav-lang">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
<a href="?culture=en-EN">EN</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="?culture=pl-PL">PL</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                
            </nav>
```

What it does is reloading the page and sets new culture - works well. The thing is, that if the user changes culture and then go to other page within my app, default culture is loaded. I checked my options and the best choice seems to be setting a cookie "UserCulture" to e.g. "c=pl-PL|uic=pl-PL". The thing is I don't really know how to do it  from  in razor pages. I think that I should have a  with asp-page-handler set to some method (e.g. "SetCulture") and have setting cookie in that method, but this  causes some problems:

- where to put "SetCulture" if the form would be in _Layout.cshtml?
  _Layout.cshtml doesn't have code behind file
- how to submit the form from *anchor*? If I put *input type="submit"* it
  ruins the look of the menu completely.. I know I could do it from js
  but I try to avoid js where it's not absolutely required, especially
  for such basic stuff..

I might be missing something very basic here, I'm quite new to Razor Pages still. From the hindsight I should have probably sticked to MVC but Razor Pages was said to be *easier*..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this out but what about setting the cookie using JavaScript and then reloading the page. The server side razor page code should check the code instead of a query parameter.

Something like the following on the _Layout page. Modify the menu to call a JS function instead of a link with a query parameter. In the JS set the cookie and reload the page.

```
<nav id="nav-lang">
    <ul>
        <li class="nav-item" onClick="setCulture('en-EN')">EN</li>
        <li class="nav-item" onClick="setCulture('pl-PL')">PL</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
...
<script>
    function setCulture(culture) {
        document.cookie = "culture="+culture;
        location.reload();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, Brad. The solution you proposed works well. In the meantime I've got also other suggestion elsewhere and I'll post it too for anyone searching the answer in future.

In _Layout.cshtml:

```
<nav id="nav-lang">
    <ul>
        <li><a asp-page="/Index" asp-page-handler="SetCulture" asp-route-culture="en-EN">EN</a></li>
        <li><a asp-page="/Index" asp-page-handler="SetCulture" asp-route-culture="pl-PL">PL</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

In code-behind of Index (or any other page having code-behind):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetSetCultureAsync(string culture)
        {
            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("Culture", "c=" + culture + "|uic=" + culture);
            var returnUrl = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
            if (returnUrl.Contains("?culture="))
            {
                var url = returnUrl.Substring(0, returnUrl.IndexOf("?culture=")); 
                return Redirect(url + "?culture=" + culture);
            }
            else
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl + "?culture=" + culture);
            }

        }
```

And of course, for both solutions to work, there  must be info in Startup.cs >> Configure:

```
var supportedCultures = new[]
            {
                new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                new CultureInfo("pl-PL")
            };

            var lo = new RequestLocalizationOptions // Localization Options
            {
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"),
                SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
                SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
            };

            var cp = lo.RequestCultureProviders.OfType<CookieRequestCultureProvider>().First(); // Culture provider
            cp.CookieName = "Culture";
```